# Setting Parameters through url javaplay

Tags: java, web-services, url, get, playframework-2.0

so as part of some work I've been doing I was given a file with WebServices that are being used in a Swift application. I have zero familiarity with WebServices and only know Java through syntax understanding. I need to call one of these gets with a parameter from the swift application. What I'm trying to figure out first and foremost is how I can call one of these webservices with a parameter from the URL it's associated with. For example down below I want to call the method

```
http://localhost:9000/ListVehicleByPlateNumber
```

and I want to specify the parameter through the URL say something like

```
http://localhost:9000/ListVehicleByPlateNumber?para="123"
```

But this doesn't assign any value to the parameter and I'm not getting results. If I hardcode so that the string used in the function is = "123" it gives me the results I'm looking for. I just need to know how I can pass this parameter through the url, syntax-wise.

Routes file

```
GET     /ListVehicleByPlateNumber controllers.NewVehicle.listVehicleByPlateNumber(para: String ?="")
```

Controller

```
public Result listVehicleByPlateNumber(String para){
    NewVehicleModel v = new NewVehicleModel();
    List<NewVehicleModel> vehiclesC = v.searchByPlateVehicle(para);
    ObjectNode wrapper = Json.newObject();
    ObjectNode msg = Json.newObject();

    if(vehiclesC != null) {
        msg.set("VehicleList", toJson(vehiclesC));
        wrapper.set("success", msg);
        return ok(wrapper);
    }else{
        msg.put("error", "There are no vehicles with the plate number");
        wrapper.set("error", msg);
        return badRequest(wrapper);
    }
}
```

Where it's called

```
public List<NewVehicleModel> searchByPlateVehicle(String plateNumber){

    Transaction t = Ebean.beginTransaction();
    List<NewVehicleModel> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT V.idNewVehicle, V.VehicleType,V.PlateNumber,V.VehicleJurisdiction,V.State,V.Vin,V.Year, " +
                "V.Make,V.modelos,V.RegistrationNumber,V.InsuranceCompany,V.PurchaseDate,V.ExpirationDate,V.idPersonaFK " +
                "FROM NewVehicle V " +
                "WHERE V.PlateNumber = :plateNumber";

        RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql)
                .columnMapping("V.idNewVehicle", "idNewVehicle")
                .columnMapping("V.State", "state")
                .columnMapping("V.VehicleType", "vehicleType")
                .columnMapping("V.PlateNumber", "plateNumber")
                .columnMapping("V.VehicleJurisdiction", "vehicleJurisdiction")
                .columnMapping("V.Vin", "vin")
                .columnMapping("V.Year", "year")
                .columnMapping("V.Make", "make")
                .columnMapping("V.modelos", "modelos")
                .columnMapping("V.RegistrationNumber", "registrationNumber")
                .columnMapping("V.InsuranceCompany", "insuranceCompany")
                .columnMapping("V.PurchaseDate", "purchaseDate")
                .columnMapping("V.ExpirationDate", "expirationDate")
                .columnMapping("V.idPersonaFK", "idPersonaFK")
                .create();

        Query<NewVehicleModel> query = Ebean.find(NewVehicleModel.class);
        query.setRawSql(rawSql)
                .setParameter("plateNumber", plateNumber);
        vehicles = query.findList();
        t.commit();


    }
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}finally {
        t.end();
    }

    return vehicles;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer. I ended up casting from Integer to String here's how it looks in routes

```
GET     /ListVehicleByPlateNumber/:para       controllers.NewVehicle.listVehicleByPlateNumber(para: Integer )
```

Controller

```
public Result listVehicleByPlateNumber(int para){
    String p = String.valueOf(para);
```

URI Format for value 123 example.

```
http://localhost:9000/ListVehicleByPlateNumber/123
```